# JQuery: .animate on $(window).scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am using the following code to keep labels for a " train time table" similar to the CSS "fixed" property to allow me to scroll the page vertically but keep the labels 'fixed' horizontally. This script works fine, but I would love to see it smoother, I have tried working with the .animate property but cannot get it to work in this case.

I can get everything working scroll wise, I just would love it to be smoother. Any help is appreciated.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      $('#tramLabels').css({
          'left': $(this).scrollLeft() +5 
      });
  });
</script>
```

Here is the rest of the code for the page as well;

```
<style type="text/css">
#tramLabels {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
}
#tramTime{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="tramLabels">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  </table> 
</div>
<div id="tramTime">
  <table width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
  </table>
</div
```

Edit: I placed the code [here for you to try](http://jsfiddle.net/F8WbW/)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by smoother? Do you want a linear animation?

Comment: If you try the code out it's jagged and stuttery because it grabs the value from scrolling, so when scrolling horizontally the labels move left and right incrementally, and flicker. .Animate should theoretically fix this by adding transitions...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      $('#tramLabels').animate({
          'left': +5 
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does nothing. The labels no longer stay afixed nor do they animate.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with .animate() and .stop(). http://jsfiddle.net/C2f7f/

Comment: This doesn't seem to replicate the behavior of the original script though, which is to keep the label left while scrolling.